# Changing Values in a column based on criteria in R

Tags: r, rename

Let's say I have a column data$code with values like 1234, 222F, 456Q, 1234, 1234...
Now I want to rename them so that every occurrence of 1234 would be 'Model 1', every occerence of 456Q -> 'Model X' etc.

I tried to make a for loop but it wouldn't work. Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please look at the link. It will be easier for us to help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from you example I assume that `code` is a categorical variable, therefore what you need to do is change a value of the levels for that variable.

For example:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
code <- c('1234', '222F', '456Q', '1234', '1234')
data <- data.frame(id, code)
data

 id code
1  1 1234
2  2 222F
3  3 456Q
4  4 1234
5  5 1234

levels(data$code)[levels(data$code)=='1234'] <- 'Model 1'
levels(data$code)[levels(data$code)=='456Q'] <- 'Model X'
data

   id    code
1  1 Model 1
2  2    222F
3  3 Model X
4  4 Model 1
5  5 Model 1
```

You simply have to repeat for every level you need to change.